# sql join returns me two same values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mysql: `matches` and `teams`, `matches` have columns `home_team` and `away_team` which are connected with `fk` in table `teams.team_id`.. I want to get those names in `home_team` and `away_team` instead their `id` ... 
I've tried this, but it returns me same value two times.. I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

Code

```
SELECT matches.home_team, matches.away_team, teams.name as home, teams.name as 
away FROM matches left join teams ON matches.home_team = teams.team_id 
left join teams as t ON matches.away_team = t.team_id
```

First value is correct, but second one no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aliases are off.  You are referring to the same first `teams` table twice in your current query.  Try this version, which distinguishes the two joined `teams` table using proper aliases.

```
SELECT
    m.home_team,
    m.away_team,
    t1.name AS home,
    t2.name AS away
FROM matches m
LEFT JOIN teams t1
    ON m.home_team = t1.team_id 
LEFT JOIN teams t2
    ON m.away_team = t2.team_id;
```

Comment: So this works, but what if I have this:  `select * from matches m JOIN teams t1 ON m.home_team = t1.team_id JOIN teams t2 ON m.away_team = t2.team_id` how can I change name, like `t1.name as home`, `t2.name as away` in this code.

Comment: @aks Using `SELECT *` is generally bad, and is arguably an anti pattern.  My answer to your follow up question is to _not_ use `SELECT *`, but rather to always list out the columns you want to select.

Comment: Aham thank you for suggestion, but in this situation I must have `SELECT *`, and now I can't get to property because both column are with same names and that's another problem...

Comment: You can't make `SELECT *` work here, because you need to explicitly refer to separate aliases to pull in the appropriate names for the home and away team.